# How do I find a basis for $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3-x^2-1 \rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I wish to find a basis for the field $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3-x^2-1 \rangle$. Treating the polynomial as the additive identity, my intuition tells me that it should be $\{1,x,x^2\}$. Thus, finding different forms of $\alpha = x + \langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$ such as $\alpha^2$ is simply done by computing and continuing to treat $x^3-x^2-1$ as  $0$. Is this correctly laid out?

Comment: Looks good to me. So if you let $\alpha = x + \langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$, then the basis for the quotient ring will be $\{\overline{1},  \alpha, \alpha^2\}$ where $\overline{1}=1+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$.

Comment: Good. So $\alpha^2$ is simply $x^2 (+ \langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle)$?

Comment: There is a distinction between $\alpha$ and $x$ to be made here: note that $x$ is a variable that appears in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$, and we quotient out by a polynomial $x^3-x^2-1$. But $\alpha$ is a coset representative of $x$ in the quotient ring. Some people like to use the notation $\overline{x}$ as opposed to $\alpha$. So, in some sense $\alpha$ denotes the value of $x$ in the quotient ring. Finally, $x$ by itself is not an element of the quotient ring, but $\alpha$ is.

Comment: Yes, $\alpha^2$ is simply $x^2+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, I needed the elaboration on the distinction between $x$ and $\alpha$

Comment: Hm, what about $\alpha^4$? Is it $(x^2 + \langle x^3-x^2-1 \rangle)^2 = x^4 + \langle x^3 - x^2 -1 \rangle$, and then I must factor out $p(x)$ somehow?

Comment: I wrote up something in the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since comment box is getting too small)

@Andrew: So let's compute $\alpha^4$. As you said, $\alpha^4 = x^4+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$. Now since $x^3-x^2-1$ becomes zero in the quotient ring, we get that $x^3+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle = (x^2+1)+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$. Now multiply both sides by $x$ to get $x^4+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle = (x^3+x)+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle$. You can rewrite this as:
$$ x^4+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle = [x^3+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle] + [x+\langle x^3-x^2-1\rangle]$$
Therefore, $\alpha^4=\alpha^3+\alpha$.

Comment: Yes, I actually figured it out myself using $\{1, x, x^2\}$ as the basis. It became a lot easier when you simply read what the quotient ring says: $Z_5[x]$ mod $p(x)$. (Well, I did get some help in the chat, but I'll claim that work that is done outside the main math.SE is original :) )

Comment: Great. :) The way I wrote above might be too formal, and less intuitive than the way you are referring to.